# How to reset the position of draggable list items in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I made a list of fruits and vegetables that the user is supposed to drag&drop into two separate divs. Here's a relevant piece of the code (which is almost the copy of the code from this tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JFkAaLOou8) :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#source li").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $("#fruits1").droppable({
        accept: 'li[data-value="fruit"]',
        drop: function (event, ui){
            $("#fruits2").append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
    $("#vegetables1").droppable({
        accept: 'li[data-value="vegetable"]',
        drop: function (event, ui){
            $("#vegetables2").append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
<script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
   <ul id="source">
      <li data-value="fruit">Banana</li>
      <li data-value="fruit">Strawberry</li>
      <li data-value="fruit">Pear</li>
      <li data-value="vegetable">Lettuce</li>
      <li data-value="vegetable">Carrot</li>
      <li data-value="vegetable">Cauliflower</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="fruits1">
   <ul id="fruits2">
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="vegetables1">
   <ul id="vegetables2">
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add a "reset" button that will bring everything to the original position after the user is done dragging & dropping list elements. How do i do that? I tried things like:

```
$("#fruits2").remove();
$("#vegetables2").remove();
```

or:

```
$("#source li").css({"left":"","top":""});
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by:

```
$("#source li").css({"left":"0px","top":"0px"});
```

Comment: this trick works well for resetting the positions of div elements but sadly doesn't seem to work with list items, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many people are facing this kind of issue and people are guessing instead of helping to know about the exact to the point solution.

Here I have made a fiddle to reset multiple objects dragged randomly via a single click. `Fiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/JunaidAli/wp1n796q/321/